# Fetch data from three columns having common columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables inline_topic_xref, embeded_media and topic_biblio_xref where TOPIC_IS and SECTION_ID are common columns in these tables. Other columns are different. How can I fetch data from three tables on the basis of the common value of this two columns? Please hep me.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a join.  Something like this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM inline_topic_xref A
 LEFT JOIN embeded_media B ON A.TOPIC_IS = B.TOPIC_IS AND A.SECTION_ID = B.SECTION_ID
 LEFT JOIN topic_biblio_xref C ON A.TOPIC_IS = C.TOPIC_IS AND A.SECTION_ID = C.SECTION_ID
```